# MIPS File Opening

Tags: io, mips

I'm trying to use MIPS Syscall 13 to simply open a file so I can read in some strings and print them to the console, but the file descriptor keeps returning as -1 when I open the file. I've checked the file extensions and everything seems to be in order. There's a file of name "cards.dat" in the same directory as the source code. Here's my code. If Anyone could help, it would be appreciated.

```
.data
filename: .asciiz "cards.dat" #file name
textSpace: .space 1050     #space to store strings to be read

.text
main:

li $v0, 13           #open a file
li $a1, 0            # file flag (read)
la $a0, filename         # load file name
add $a2, $zero, $zero    # file mode (unused)
syscall
move $a0, $v0        # load file descriptor
li $v0, 14           #read from file
la $a1, textSpace        # allocate space for the bytes loaded
li $a2, 1050         # number of bytes to be read
syscall  
la $a0, textSpace        # address of string to be printed
li $v0, 4            # print string
syscall
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are giving MIPS a file name like you have in your code. The MIPS .jar must be in the same directory as the file; not your source code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that the working directory is the one you are expecting, as you using relative paths. That is, `cards.dat` needs to be in the working directory of your program.
The code seems just fine. Try using an absolute path in `filename` if you know the exact location of the file you want to open.

E.g.:

```
filename: .asciiz "c:\\files\\cards.dat" #file name
```

Another thing you may experiment to get the working directory is to create a file within your code and then look into the filesystem where that file gets created... For that, use service 13 with `$a1` set to 1 (write flag).

Also, don't forget to use service 16 to close the file handle after you have used it. It's one of those best practices you should definitely do.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks !  
Pay attention on double `\\`.