Im trying to open a file and read the contents in my MIPS program, but i dont know what im doing wrong
I have a bigger project im working on, where i have to take the lines of the file and output them at specific points, but im not able to open this file. I decided to make a smaller project where i just open the file and output whats inside, but that isnt working either. I added screenshots to show my program aswell as my directory.
.data
    buffer:     .space 1024  # Increased buffer size
    filename:   .asciiz "C:\Users\mmoma\Documents\prac\input.txt"
.text
.globl main


main:
    # Open and read file
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, filename
    li $a1, 0
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0

   #read the fi;le
   li $v0, 14
   move $a0, $s0
   la $a1, buffer
   la $a2, 1024
   syscall 
   
   #print file 
   li $v0,4 
   la $a0, buffer 
   syscall 
   
   #close the file
   li $v0, 16
   move $a0, $s0
   syscall

enter image description here
Here is a picture of my folder to show that I have input in the same folder.
I expected the file to be read and outputted, but nothing happened. The file compiles, then just ends when i run it.

First you should try to see in a debugger (or directly in the simulator if you are using one) where it first goes wrong. The most obvious would be the syscalls failing. Check the return values of the syscalls.

16 for close... so you are using SPIM? Anyway, you probably should use double "" in the path as in "C:\\Users\\mmoma\\.... If that helps, then maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027871/mips-file-opening

@teapot418 i spent 4 hours trying to resolve this issue and you saved me. I cannot thank you enough, tea is my favorite drink now
